# Trouble downloading playwright for python

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/elebumm/RedditVideoMakerBot

And I'm encountering this issue:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement playwright==1.23.0 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for playwright==1.23.0

I'm on a Windows 10-b4bit, but I've tried both 64 and 32-bit versions, and it won't work.

I tried downloading it from https://pypi.org/project/playwright/1.25.2/#files.

But when I try to install it I get this error:

> ERROR: playwright-1.25.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I tried downloading it using node and git but it still won't let me run the next commands:

- `python -m playwright install`
- `python -m playwright install-deps`

Comment: Playwright is only available for Python 3.7 and above. Are you using that version? Also you can try to download the dependencies using this command first: ```pip install playwright-deps
``` then doing ```pip install playwright```

Comment: I have python 3.10, I got the same error trying the pip install playwright-deps:
C:\Users\Romo>pip install playwright-deps
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement playwright-deps (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for playwright-deps

C:\Users\Romo>pip install playwright
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement playwright (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for playwright

Comment: Have you upgraded pip? Sometimes that can cause issues if pip is out of date.